# I'm getting a ImproperlyConfigured error when I run my code

Tags: python, django

It says that my CreateView is missing a queryset, but I think it doesn't need one. So the form won't appear on the page. In my previous projects it doesn't need a get_queryset function. I tried to find code with the similar error but the cause of those problems where misspells and other syntax error.

I am using Django 3.1.4

[image: This is the error]

Here is my views.py:

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
template_name = "about.html"


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(publish_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-publish_date')

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blogapp/post_detail.html'
    model = Post
    
    form_class = PostForm
    def get_queryset(self):
        

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blogapp/post_detail.html'
    model = Post
    
    form_class = PostForm


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    model = Post
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(publish_date__isnull=True).order_by('create_date')
```

Comment: you have empty `def get_queryset(self):` in `class PostCreateView` - you should put some code or use word `pass` to create empty function.

Comment: its a typo, the `get_queryset()` method of  `PostCreateView` should be completed

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the code. get_queryset is not properly defined in the CreateView.
Comment get_queryset or write it as below

```
def get_queryset(self):
     pass
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Does this solve your issue or do you still face any error? Can you put the exact error in here